# How can I target a specific button that occurs after a specific div?

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

I am having trouble targeting a specific button with CSS. A div dynamically appears when Google Pay and/or Apple Pay is available to the user on my shop. The normal Add to Cart button does not match the shape and size of the Google Pay / Apple Pay button, so I want to restyle it to match. If Google Pay / Apply Pay is not available, I don't want to restyle the button.

when Google Pay / Apple Pay is available, the div with class "__PrivateStripeElement" is interjected into the code somewhere above the Add to cart button. I can't seem to get the right selectors in my css to target the button in this circumstance. I have tried many selectors and combinations, but I can't seem to crack it.

A product page to use as a reference would be https://youmeitea.com/product/long-jing-green-tea/.

I will also include a screenshot.

[image]

Comment: You may want to use the `~` general sibling selector if they are on the same DOM level. So `.a ~ .b` will select b only when a is there. Otherwise you will have to add conditional CSS based on Woocommerce hooks.

Comment: I tried using that selector with no luck. What is meant by the same DOM level?

Comment: The two elements are adjacent and not that one belongs to a different parent or nested inside another.

Comment: I gave a specific example Website for the code, but as I understand what you are saying, it appears they are not in the same level. Is there another way to select this button when that div appears?

Comment: Give me account details where I can see both the buttons.

Comment: (Sorry I didn't reply until now!) You can see the buttons without creating an account. This "Buy now" button shows on devices that support Google Pay or Apple Pay.

Comment: I see it like this: https://nimb.ws/vTWVq9